# Is there a way to get the Handle or CWnd* of a control using the ID of the control

Tags: c++, mfc, hwnd, cwnd

If I have an MFC dialog with a button control on it, is there a way to get construct the HWND or CWND for that control using the button's ID (e.g IDC_BUTTON_YES)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d16yhw.aspx

Comment: If you use GetDlgItem to get the CWnd pointer, do not store it for later use.  There's no guarantee it will be valid later on as it may be a temporary pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the function GetDlgItem of the MFC dialog!

Here is an example for you:

```
CWnd*  myWnd = this->GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1);

// as CListBox

CListBox* myListBox = (CListBox*)this->GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1);
```